# Accessing WP7 Contacts

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sms

I have a project going where I want to automate an SMS and have a time and date to push out the SMS to a specific contact. So how do I pull the contacts from the phone in a neat and efficient manner? Basically I want the user to push a button then the app goes to the contacts list and the user then checks off or clicks a name and that gets stored into a string.

Also, if anyone could give me a hint on how to schedule the sms and get it to launch once the time has arrived, that would be helpful! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [PhoneNumberChooser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394021%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). And you can't queue a SMS to send, really. The user has the final input for security reasons. You could make your app open the SMS screen after a specified time period, but that's a horrible idea.

To send SMS, you'll want [SMSComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394005%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Microsoft.Phone.UserData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)